# (MacOS Command line) When using arrow keys to browse command history, previous commands concatenate, not deleting themselves

Tags: macos, haskell, terminal, ghc, ghci

For context: I think I pressed something wrong while writing a command, but didn't pay much attention, then I noticed that if I went back with the up-arrow key, and then used the down-arrow key, the previous commands where concatenated:

(It may be important to note that this only happens using GHCi --Glasgow Haskell Compiler interactive environment)

```
% ghci
GHCi, version 8.10.7: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> x = 2
Prelude> y = 2
Prelude> x + y
4
Prelude> x + y = x = y = x +
```

The last line was "written" using only the arrow keys, after using them a few times, they can't be deleted, but if I actually write something after it, the previous commands are ignored:
for reference:

{} - concatenated unintentionally with arrow keys

[] - written by me

```
Prelude> {x + y = x} [2 + 2]
4
```

^the above, if written only by me, without using arrow keys, would've thrown an error.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It turns that, quoting a member from the Function Programming Discord, "it's a known issue with haskeline (the library GHCi) uses that been fixed but needs to be back ported into GHC itself"

A workaround suggested by the same person is running `TERM=dumb ghci`

Comment: I was also able to fix this by upgrading from 8.10.7 to 9.2.4 with `ghcup set ghc 9.2.4`. Alas 8.10.7 is still (a year later) the last "recommend" version, and several important third party tools don't support the newer versions yet.

Comment: yes, that's another way, and at least for me, ghc-9.0.2 also works without problems